# How to pass a list of File in Intend - Android

Tags: android, list, file, android-intent

I have a list of files and I want to pass them to another activity through Intend

```
List<File> list = ((PDFs) pdfs).getPdfList();
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Merge_PDF.class);
intent1.putParcelableArrayListExtra("pdfList", list);
```

getPdfList will return a List of Files

Comment: Why pass files? And not their paths instead? You can always get a reference to a file using the path

Comment: I will do that thank you